# Graded commutator defines graded derivation?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, algebras, graded-algebras

${}$

I'm having difficulties understanding what to do on a problem for my exercise class. The problem is as follows:

${}$

---

Consider a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ graded algebra $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{A}_0 \oplus \mathcal{A}_1$ together with its graded derivations
$$ \delta \in \text{Der}_{\pm} (\mathcal{A}) : \; \mathcal{A}_i \longrightarrow \mathcal{A}_{i+\deg(\delta)} \quad ,$$
$$\delta(ab) \enspace = \enspace \delta(a)b + (-1)^{\deg(a)\deg(\delta)}a\delta(b) \quad , \qquad  (\ast)$$
where
$$\deg(a) \enspace = \enspace \begin{cases} 0 \; , \quad a \in \mathcal{A}_0 \\ 1 \; , \quad a \in \mathcal{A}_1 \end{cases}$$
and $\deg(\delta) = 0$ for derivations and $\deg(\delta) = 1$ for antiderivations.

${}$

Show that the graded commutator
$$\big[ \delta_1, \delta_2 \big]_{\pm} \enspace = \enspace \delta_1 \delta_2 - (-1)^{\deg(\delta_1)\deg(\delta_2)} \delta_1 \delta_2$$
defines again a graded derivation (with $\deg\big( [\delta_1, \delta_2]\big) = \deg(\delta_1) + \deg(\delta_2) \; \text{mod} \; 2$).

---

${}$

I don't quite get the following: $\;$ My commutator $f(x,y) \equiv [x,y]$ needs two arguments. To show that a map is a graded derivation, I need to show that my map fullfills equation $(\ast)$. However, this equations is defined for a map having only one argument. What do I misunderstand? What do I need to do?

${}$

Comment: Are you familiar with the ungraded case to begin with?

Comment: You mean that the ungraded commutator defines again an ungraded derivation? I'm not familiar with it, though the problem seems to be the same (regarding the number of arguments)

Comment: Yes, the problem is the same, but you might have been familiar with this more classical case, and been confused by the addition of the grading. In any case, consider the function $y\mapsto [x,y]$.

Comment: Ah, so my commutator/derivation is actually: $f_x : y \mapsto [x,y]$, meaning it has only one argument. The solution for the classical case would then be:

$$ f_x(yz) \equiv [x,yz] = xyz - yzx = xyz - yxz + yxz - yzx = [x,y]z + y[x,z] = f_x(y)z + yf_x(z) $$

right? So I just calculate the same for the graded version.

Comment: That is exactly right.

Comment: Thank you, I'll post again later to check my answer for the above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are required to prove that the *commutator of two derivations* is again a derivation, no that the commutator (seen itself as a antisymmetric bilinear map) is a derivation.

Comment: Ah, ok, I get your point. In this case, how do I interpret the product of two derivations as outlined below:

If
$$[\delta_1, \delta_2](ab) = \Big( \delta_1\delta_2 - (-1)^{\deg(\delta_1)\deg(\delta_2)}\delta_2\delta_1 \Big)(ab) = \delta_1\delta_2(ab) - (-1)^{\deg(\delta_1)\deg(\delta_2)} \delta_2\delta_1 (ab)$$

then what is the term $\delta_1 \delta_2 (ab)$? Is it to be understood as $\delta_1(ab) \delta_2(ab)$ or rather as $\delta_1 \big( \delta_2 (ab) \big)$? I guess the latter is true, but I want go make sure this is correct.

Comment: @Octavius Yes, the latter.

Comment: @Octavius Also for the commutator itself acting as a derivation with respect to the product of a commutative algebra, look up the notion of a Poisson algebra.